# FCM not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a FCM program for notification.
Since it's work normally in Chrome / Firefox.

But today, every Chrome in different device can't receive push message (including onMessage event / service worker). But it's works on Firefox.

Anyone got the same problems?

Comment: Hi Steven. Please reach out to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) along with the details. It would also be helpful if you post additional details (related code snippets, logs, testing you've done) here.